# Bulging in the wall and ceiling

Tags: drywall, walls, ceiling, new-home

I purchased a new construction home just a month ago that has a year of warranty. I have started noticing bulges in the wall and ceiling. Is it poor construction? There are several like these.

- How hard or easy is it to fix?
- Is it concerning?

Please let me know your thoughts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks more like a lousy finish.  Fixing is more of a messy time job than hard.  Sanding, scraping, redoing, and painting over.

Comment: Is it concerning for future?

Comment: Just for looks.  It is probably more of a bad looking finish coating than construction problem.  Would record it and send a copy to builder, but a house will take time to settle, so doing any fixing right now will probably just need to done later also(maybe not the same spots).

Comment: Are you able to check for signs of leaking above the relevant walls?

Comment: Make sure to document and inform the builder with registered letter since they absolutely will refuse to touch this one the second the warranty expires and unless you can legally prove the problem existed before it expired and prove you informed them they will not honor the warranty.   I have seen a lot of this in friends houses BTW.  Thin drywall, lumber that isn't fully cured, construction during the winter when a few rainstorms move through and the builder doesn't have a roof on it, all of this is cheap construction practices and contributes to the problem.

Comment: Definitely document and contact your builder/warranty company. It's concerning that a brand new house would exhibit such issues, but it's not concerning in a "life threatening, house is about to fall down" sort of way.

Comment: Also, go through your whole house with a powerful flashlight skimming along the walls and photograph & document all the questionable areas. An experienced professional with pride wouldn't have left it like this, and it is sub-par by subjective standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing but shoddy workmanship on a brand new home.

Contact the builder and/or warranty company immediately and ask when they'll be out to fix it.

Document. Document. Document! Do everything in writing - email at a minimum, certified letters if they get snippy with you. If they call to discuss it, take notes, then summarize the phone conversation *immediately* in an email message back to them to put it in writing. Something like:

> Dear Builder's Representative,
>
> Thank you for your phone call of *date* at *time*. Per our discussion, here are the actions you will be taking and the date they are to be completed:
> *list here*
> and here are the actions that you expect me to take:
> *list here*
> If I've missed anything, please let me know immediately so I can update my records.
>
> Thank you,
> Nikhil

Is this concerning? Yes, it's concerning that they built the house so poorly. Is this likely to collapse on you at any moment, no, I wouldn't think so, but who knows where else shoddy workmanship is lurking.

Make sure you keep a very close eye on your house for any other signs of damage and notify them immediately.

Comment: Yeah I'd be worried about related shoddy invisible workmanship elsewhere, like framing or drywall under tension causing future mud cracks.

Answer (score 0):

I am a drywall finisher/taper. This might be a case of bad drywall finishing. The taper might not have prefilled the joint before taping, which leads to the tape blistering/bubbling. The straight line looks like there's definitely a joint there and the tape is coming apart because there is not enough mud behind it.